# Exception error with cache:clear with Class Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector

Tags: php, caching, doctrine-orm, composer-php

When I run `composer update` I get the following error when the `cache:clear` script is called.

```
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector' not found in /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Util/Inflector.php on line 29

  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                                                                                                 
  PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector' not found in /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Util/Inflector.php on line 29                                              
  PHP Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  PHP   1. Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleException() /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php:0                                                           
  PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->handleError() /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ErrorHandler.php:557                         
  PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->getClassCandidates() /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/FatalErrorHandler/ClassNotFoundFatal  
  ErrorHandler.php:62                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->findClassInPath() /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/FatalErrorHandler/ClassNotFoundFatalErr  
  orHandler.php:118                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->convertFileToClass() /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/FatalErrorHandler/ClassNotFoundFatal  
  ErrorHandler.php:143                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  PHP   6. require_once() /home/sarah/workspace/telematics_tracker/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/FatalErrorHandler/ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php:188                                                              
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Composer.json

```
{
    ...

    "require" : {
        ...
        "doctrine/common" : "^2.7",
        "doctrine/dbal" : "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle" : "^1.2",
        "doctrine/orm" : "^2.5",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "^2.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "^3.0.2",
        "sensio/generator-bundle" : "^3.1",
    },
    "require-dev\"" : {
        "sensio/generator-bundle" : "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge" : "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit" : "^5.6",
        "phpunit/php-invoker" : "^1.1"
    },
    "scripts" : {
        "post-root-package-install" : "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall",
        "post-install-cmd" : [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd" : [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
            "Mopa\\Bundle\\BootstrapBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::postInstallSymlinkTwitterBootstrap"
        ]
    },
    "extra" : {
        "symfony-app-dir" : "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir" : "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir" : "var",
        "symfony-web-dir" : "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir" : "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install" : "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters" : {
            "file" : "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability" : "dev"
}
```

Inflector.php is in the correct place with the following contents.

```
<?php
/*
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS
 * "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT
 * OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL,
 * SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
 * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
 * DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
 * THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
 * (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE
 * OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 *
 * This software consists of voluntary contributions made by many individuals
 * and is licensed under the MIT license. For more information, see
 * <http://www.doctrine-project.org>.
 */

namespace Doctrine\Common\Util;

use Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector as BaseInflector;

/**
 * Doctrine inflector has static methods for inflecting text.
 *
 * Kept for backwards compatibility reasons, was moved to its own component.
 */
class Inflector extends BaseInflector
{
}
```

I see the comment in the docblock `Kept for backwards compatibility reasons, was moved to its own component`.

Does anyone know where it has been moved to?

How do I get cache:clear to call the correct class?

Comment: The package is named [doctrine/inflector](https://github.com/doctrine/inflector/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running `composer update` this morning installed the new version of doctrine/inflector `Installing doctrine/inflector (1.2.x-dev e11d84c)` and I am no longer getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

update your `php` version to `7.2` or higher